# Property "identifier" does not exist in class "AppBundle\Entity\User"

Tags: php, forms, symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-2.8

I'm trying to get a user registration form to work in Symfony-2.8 and have been following the KNP University content. I have setup the User Entity, the UserFormType and have created the UserController with a view. Everything works just fine when rendering the form. It renders perfectly with the CSRF token etc. The issue is when i submit the form. The error that is displayed is:
`Property "identifier" does not exist in class "AppBundle\Entity\User"` a `ValidatorException`. Searching Google does not bring up anything, which leads me to believe its something simple.

Actual log error:

```
[2016-07-30 17:41:52] request.CRITICAL:
    Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Validator\Exception\ValidatorException:
    "Property "identifier" does not exist in class "AppBundle\Entity\User"" at 
/var/projects/clients/perfect.symfony-2x.dev/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Validator/Mapping/PropertyMetadata.php line 42 
{
    "exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Validator\\Exception\\ValidatorException(code: 0):
    Property \"identifier\" does not exist in class \"AppBundle\\Entity\\User\" at
    /var/projects/clients/perfect.symfony-2x.dev/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Validator/Mapping/PropertyMetadata.php:42)"
} []
```

In despiration I trashed my code and copied and pasted the code from Symfony's example and still I come up with the same error. You'll find the example from Symfony here:

https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/doctrine/registration_form.html

Can anyone shed some light as to where to troubleshoot this. In my case Google has not been very helpful :(

Comment: That link indicates you must also properly setup your security.yml and the UserInterface interface.  I suspect you have not correctly done the latter.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You were 100% correct, there was a validation file under Resources->config->validation.yml which had the following: 

identifier:
            - Uuid: ~

Thanks again :)